# Terraform - Auto-populate required attributes in IDE

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, terraform

I took a class recently with the exceptional Yevgeniy Brikman, and as he created Terraform resources, his IDE auto-populated required attributes.  For instance, if he typed:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_example" {
```

His IDE would auto-populate:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_example" {
  function_name = ""
  handler       = ""
  runtime       = ""
  role          = ""
}
```

Now that I'm writing Terraform code frequently this feature would be handy, but I can't find a way to configure my IDE to do this (Visual Studio Code).  I'm up for switching IDEs - how does one get this functionality?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hashicorp (the company behind Terraform) publish a plugin for IntelliJ IDEA that has a lot of spiffy functionality.

This picture is a result of me defining an empty lambda, then pressing Alt-Enter:
[image: empty resource with popup]

Selecting that first entry populates the mandatory properties as you showed.
Then after that, I put my cursor inside the resource and press Ctrl-Space, to have IDEA show code completion options for all the other optional properties:
[image: populated resource with popup]

I'm a keyboard user, so that's what I know to do.  I'm sure you can do all sorts of mousery if that's what floats your boat.

I use the commercial version of IDEA, but there is a free community version and I assume the Hashicorp plugin would work with that.

Comment: anything for atom?

Comment: @BMW You can only get autocomplete with Atom, plus the validater/formatter package I made. There is nothing yet to support the mandatory properties snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the plugin **Terraform doc snippets** then the values will get auto-populated.

[View the plugin image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tf9eo.png)

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yanlP.png) to view the `use tf-aws-resource-instance` resource block and attributes that will popup in VSCode